# Export "Document Version" Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Question. How can I include "document version" column when I use the "export to excel" function in sharepoint 2019 on premise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to my research, "**Export to Excel**" cannot export document's Versions.

You can run the below powershell script as an admin to export all files to CSV.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

#Change the site collection url
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://sp19:81/sites/echo"

#change the library or list name
$List = $SPWeb.Lists["Documents"]

$ReportOutput = "C:\Temp\mex-DocInventory.csv"
$Pagesize = 500

#Delete the Output report file if exists
If (Test-Path $ReportOutput) { Remove-Item $ReportOutput}
 
#Array to store results
$Results = @()

$ItemsColl = $List.Items

ForEach($Item in $ItemsColl){

    $itemFileSize = $Item.File.Length/1KB
 
    foreach($Ver in $Item.Versions)
     {
        if($Ver.IsCurrentVersion){
        $verFileSize = $Item.File.Versions.GetVersionFromLabel($Ver.VersionLabel).Size/1KB
        $v = new-object psobject
        $comment = $Item.File.Versions.GetVersionFromLabel($Ver.VersionLabel).CheckInComment
           
        $v | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name "File Title" -value $Item.Name
        $v | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name "Created By" -value $Ver["Author"]
        $v | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name "Item URL" -value $Ver.Url
        $v | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name "Version" -value $Ver.VersionLabel
        $v | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name "Created Date" -value $Ver["Created"]
        
        $Results += $v;
       }

     }
}

$Results | Export-Csv -Path $ReportOutput -NoTypeInformation

Write-host "Document Library Inventory Exported to CSV Successfully!"
```

[image]

[image]